# Where can I find large php5 best practices project?

Tags: php, unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm trying to find a project that incorporates the "best practices" that are discussed and debated on a daily basis for almost all languages but I'm trying to focus on php5.

Is there a php5 open source project that I can comb through to see working examples of project that exemplifies Units Tests, Dependency Injection and other best practices

I'm basically researching for a new large project and wanted to see a shining example project in all it's glory instead of the snippets of code that are endlessly debated.  Since this project will not inherit a whole bunch of legacy code I'm really trying to get things right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for something like [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)!

Comment: yes i use ZF too! and i am starting to like it. the learning curve maybe steep but it think its worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Kohana Framework](http://kohanaphp.com) too. In fact, most of the popular frameworks have great PHP code. I can not say the same for Wordpress, osCommerce, etc. Magento seems to be OK, maybe a little over engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of few libraries which are having good php standards

```
Laravel - PHP Framework with tons of goodies
Guzzle - CURL library
PHPUnit - PHP Testing Framework
Carbon - DateTime handling library
Faker - For generating fake data
```

Many more are there, the following link will help you more

https://github.com/uhub/awesome-php